# Performance expectations for an Amazon RDS instance

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Google App Engine for an app, and the app is currently hitting the datastore at a rate of around 2.5 million row writes, and 4.5 million row reads per day.

I am currently porting the app to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk and Amazon RDS due to the very high costs of running an application on GAE.

Based on the values above, how can I find out / estimate what type of RDS instance I will need for my requirements? Is the above a considerable amount of processing for, lets say a Small or Micro MySQL RDS instance to process in a day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally depends on a number of factors:

- Row size.
- Field types and sizes.
- Complexity of your queries (joins, etc).
- Proper use of indexes.
- Row contention and other possible bottlenecks.

Really hard to tell. But from experience, if you don't need fancy replication or sharding, the costs of the GAE datastore are usually higher as it offers total redundancy, distribution, scalability, etc.

My suggestion would be to write a quick program to benchmark a load on RDS that replicates what you are expecting. Should be easy to write if you forgo all the business rules and such and just do fake but randomized reads and writes.